# Where can I download Egit for Eclipse Helios?

Tags: windows-7, eclipse, egit, helios

I cannot find any place to download `Egit for Eclipse Helios`. Even in the links provided in http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/ not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I'm using windows-7 and my `eclipse version is 1.3.0`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Latest EGit version supporting Helios is 2.1.0, see this [wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_versions_of_Eclipse_does_EGit_target.3F) and find p2 repository links [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_older_releases_of_EGit.3F). If you want a newer EGit version (latest is 3.1.0) you need to upgrade to a newer Eclipse version.